# XSD error: Cannot find the declaration of element

Tags: xml, xsd

I have gone through the same issues other peopla had about this but nothing seemed to work

Here is My XML file:

```
<Livraria xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns:x="x:livro.xsd" 
      xsi:schemaLocation="livro.xsd LivrariaScheme.xsd">
<Secção nome="Não Ficção">
    <Livros>
        <Livro Secção="Não Ficção">
```

And here is my XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema version="1.0"
       attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
       elementFormDefault="qualified"
       xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
       targetNamespace="x:livro.xsd"
       xmlns:x="livro.xsd"
```

>

```
<xs:element name="Livraria" type="x:TLivraria">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Secção" type="x:Secção"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="TSecção">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Livros" type="x:TLivros"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="TLivros">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Livro" type="x:TLivro" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I keep getting this error:

```
cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'Livraria'.[6]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

A XSD like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           targetNamespace="remove_me"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="Livraria" type="TLivraria"/>

    <xs:complexType name="TLivraria">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Secção" type="TSecção"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="TSecção">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Livros" type="TLivros"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="nome" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="TLivros">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Livro" type="TLivro" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="TLivro">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="TLivro"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

will support a XML like that

```
<Livraria xmlns="remove_me">
    <Secção nome="Não Ficção">
        <Livros>
            <Livro>
                <name>Funny book</name>
            </Livro>
        </Livros>
    </Secção>
</Livraria>
```

The primary problem is that your xsd does not have targetNameSpace and your XML does not reference it (the 'xmlns' attribute). But the whole XML and XSD of yours are quite broken.